# ReactJS - Maximum stack exceeded when child component calls a function from its parent

Tags: reactjs

I have a child component (which calls another component) and I call a function from its parent:

Here is the render method in child component:

```
render() {
    ...
        return (
            <secondChild
                getName={(name) => {
                     this.props.(handleName(name))
                  }
               }
            />
   );
```

In the parent component I will use setState:

```
handleName = (name) => {
    …
    this.setState(….);
 }
```

the setState in the parent cause a re-render so the the child will be re-rendered. this led to an infinite loop and eventually cause “maximum stack exceeded ..."

I wonder why the child will immediately calls the function after re-render? should I change `getName`? [because it is an arrow function]

How can I change my code to avoid this loop?

Comment: how does `child` use `getName` that is passed from `props`? (if I understood your description of the code correctly).

Comment: @margaretkru you are right, I made a mistake and I didn't mentioned where the getName comes from. I have edited my question.

Comment: is `secondChild` calling `getName` somewhere?

Comment: yes, like : getName={this.props.getName(this.state.name)}

Comment: so you update `state` of the parent component during rendering the child components? why do you need to change state of the parent during the render phase of the child components? You usually change `state` in response to some user action, or after fetching some data from the api, but not during just displaying your data.

Comment: exactly, I have both "user action" and "api call" in the child component. the user selects different dates and names ... and I should reflect these changes in another child of the parent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially generating an infinite loop. While we do not have the code for child component, if you call getName at least once every time it gets rendered, this will cause the issue.

One way of solving it would be to make child component unable to re-render. By giving it;

`shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
}`

you can ensure it gets rendered only once. Note that, this function is extendable and depending on nextProps and nextState you can make it so that it does not re-render when props get updated but when state does, or skip re-rendering for some changes but not others.

For example, following code will re-render only when component's state gets updated;

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    let stateHasChanged = false;
    Object.keys(nextState).forEach((stateKey) => {
        if (this.state[stateKey] !== nextState[stateKey]) {
            stateHasChanged = true;
        }
    });

    return stateHasChanged;
}
```

A quick disclaimer, as pointed out in comments, is that you should try to respect React's lifecycle and not resort to setState in renders. However, should you wish to do so, this is how.

Comment: what if the child component has its own state? do we really want to just disable rerender of the component?

Comment: @margaretkru I have updated the answer to better accommodate your concerns. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: -1 While this does "solve" the OPs problem, such a solution is more of a quickhack/workaround that can potentially cause more problems as the codebase gets more complex. A better way would be to respect React component lifecycle and **NOT** call `setState` while components are being rendered.

Comment: @Yakimych That is correct. Answer is about how does one get said result, not the best practise. I am issuing a warning in the answer, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs probably because you are trying to change `state` of you parent component during rendering you child components. This will cause an infinite loop because state changes cause component to rerender, which means the parent will rerender its children causing them call the same method that updates `state` of the parent etc.

You usually change state in response to some user action, or after fetching some data from the api, but not during rendering your component. If you need to fetch data from the api and set it on the state you use `componentDidMount`, see [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount). Like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    // safe to call setState here
    this.setState({ name : 'value' });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try an `isChildMounted` state in parent like this:

in the parent component:

```
handleName = (name) => {
    if(!this.state.isChildMounted){
        this.setState({
             isChildMounted: true,
             ...
             ...
         });
    }
 }
```